# How can I install gitea on heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli, gitea

Here is the [repository](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/gitea-installer.sh/src/branch/master) which I'm referring to. It has this 
`curl -fsSL https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/gitea-installer.sh/raw/branch/master/install.bash | bash` command to install gitea server on linux at port 3000. How can make heroku run this command, I tried heroku bash and ran command over there and it failed.

Comment: Something that's important to know: `heroku run bash` starts a new, temporary instance. Any changes you make there are not permanent; they go away as soon as you close it, and they don't affect your webserver at all. It's intended for running stuff like database migrations or debugging code that isn't working, not for making changes to your app's code.

Comment: If you review https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/gitea-installer.sh/raw/branch/master/install.bash, there are a lot of things there that probably won't work on Heroku.

Comment: That's bad :( Should try this [Installation with Docker](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/install-with-docker/) given on gitea docs on heroku instead.

Comment: It might be the wrong type of service for you, but it's not "bad". It's simply a platform-as-a-service provider, not a VPS or similar.

Comment: Also, what does "it failed" mean? In the future, please make sure to include _exact error messages_. See [ask].